# Trigger a Python Tool via Azure automation

Tags: azure-automation, dbt

I have a below scenario which I am currently doing manually:

1. Install DBT tool (python) in my system :
   https://www.getdbt.com/
2. Clone a repo in my system which contains the code that needs to be executed by the tool (DBT)
3. Trigger the tool via command line (CLI)
   https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-commands

example : we have a command like dbt run -- model1

Now I need to automate it in Upper environments and able to parameterise certain aspects like be able to execute commands based on parameters :
dbt run -- <>

Is it possible to install the python package, clone Git Repo and execute CLI commands at run time via Azure automation or having some powershell code via VM

Note: we tried the below approach but unable to parameterise the queries

https://medium.com/hashmapinc/integrating-dbt-with-azure-data-factory-adf-3d7f66272433

Comment: Duplicate - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/723204/index.html